# .NET5 on OSX - C# errors in DNVM shell (so close..)

Tags: asp.net, macos, dnx, dnvm, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to get an old project to run on the new .NET VM, I've gotten through a few obstacles at this point. For a while I couldn't get DNVM to recognize my project as a .NET project, until I added a couple missing files from a sample project, and used `dnvm . kestrel` instead of `dnvm . web` and then I got back about 80mb worth of C# errors...

So I went from not being recognized as a project, to being recognized as a shitty one :/

Anybody beat this level yet? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Two questions for you

1. When you say that you tried `dnvm . kestrel`, do you mean that you tried `dnx . kestrel`?
2. Did you run `dnu restore` to download dependencies before running `dnu . kestrel`?

## Three command line programs

There are three command line programs that you will use to run a .NET 5 app, and it's easy to confuse them. `dnvm` is the version manager, `dnu` is the utility, and `dnx` is the runtime. It's the runtime not the version manager that you use from your project's root folder to start the kestrel web server.

## Startup up an app

Here's the very short version of how to start up a .NET 5 app. After using `dnvm` to install .NET 5, and after creating a project (and optionally a solution,) you need to use both `dnu` and `dnx` in this sequence.

1. From your solution's folder, run `dnu restore`. This will download your project's dependencies. If you have only a project and no solution, run this from your project's folder instead.
2. From your project's folder, run `dnx . kestrel` to run the web application in the browser.

It sounds like you did number (2) without having first done number (1).

Let me know whether you're able to reach the next level. Also, have you read these articles?

- http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html
- http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html